# Android Robotium - How do you detect a context menu?

Tags: android, robotium

I'm writing a Robotium test where I long press an item in a list to bring up a context menu. I need to somehow detect the context menu in my tearDown so I can back out of it and sign out of the application. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a better way of doing it with the latest Robotium version, but we found a functional hack in earlier versions:

```
  private ListView getContextMenuListView(){
    ArrayList<ListView> currentListViews = solo.getCurrentListViews();
    for (ListView lv : currentListViews){
      String listViewClassName = lv.getClass().getName();
      if (listViewClassName.startsWith("com.android.internal.app.AlertController$RecycleListView")){
        return lv;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Note that, as with everything else, you need to *wait* for the listview to pop up. If you immediately try to find it you might miss it, especially when running in emulators.

Comment: Thanks, though this looks rather cumbersome and fragile as it relies on a name from an internal package. Is there no getCurrentlyOpenedContextMenu() method or other more supported means available? I've looked through the APIs and couldn't find one.

Comment: Yeah, seems we're out of luck for now :/

Answer (score 0):

finishOpenedActivities should close down any and all activities you have open but i am assuming you need to do something specific to clear the state of your application in your tear down method. In that case you are going to have to check for the existence of the context menu, which I assume you have code to do because you are doing things tot eh context menu (or look at dmons answer).

The second option of course and what might be worth the time investing in doing is to build into your application/test infrastructure a simple way to remove all state so that your tear downs are consistent and all start with no previous state, doing this in the long run will make your tests better and allow quicker development because typically anytime you have to remember to do x and y and z to clear state you will forget one of them one time and it will be a pain to track down.

Comment: In this case I'm testing a context menu. If the assert fails I need a reliable way to recover from the assertion failure which leaves the context menu open. I'd also like to detect if the context menu is open as part of my test.